# Is there kgdb for kernel 2.6.37?

Tags: kgdb

I am having trouble using kgdb in kernel.
I suspect that kgdb is available obly for specific linux version, and 2.6.37 is none of them ?
Trying to search patch for 2.6.37 in web, does not give results.
Is there anyone who knows or tires kgdb ? Is there anything that can be done to make it work with 2.6.37 ?

Thanks , Ran

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.linux.kernel/Rs5nOU2CmBo

Answer (score 1):

After kernel 2.6.35, both kgdb and kdb are embedded in kernel source tree, so there are no patched file for them. So I believe that you can directly configure the kernel and build it.

You can have a try. good luck